# Is it fair to use Entity Framework just as an ORM tool without even thinking of DDD or models etc?

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have a database and bunch of related tables . I just want to use EF to reduce Data-Access code for CRUD operations on those table. I dont want to change the model or anything. I am using the models as It is generated(or using POCO). Is it fair to use EF just for this(to reduce the data-access code) or  it is overkill and i should think about DDD. Any directions?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915558/asp-net-and-entity-framework-in-layered-architecture-using-entity-framework-for) is a good question. Any other thought?

**EDIT**

I just wanted to ask If that is a good idea to use this just as an ORM. Honestly, I am very new to EF and know nothing about DDD and just wanted to use EF to reduce data-access code I have been writing all this while

Comment: Have you just posted a question telling us it is a duplicate and linked to the original?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET and Entity Framework in Layered Architecture - using Entity Framework for ORM only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915558/asp-net-and-entity-framework-in-layered-architecture-using-entity-framework-for)

Comment: @Oded - Sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to ask If that is a good idea to use this just as an ORM. Honestly, I am very new to EF and know nothing about DDD and just wanted to use EF to reduce data-access code I have been writing all this while.

Comment: I understand this, however the question you linked to provides perfectly good answers to the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Entity Framework without knowing or implementing DDD.  DDD does not require an ORM or a relational database.  Using an ORM does not imply that you must, or even that you should, use DDD.

Many people who implement DDD on top of a relational database use an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate and it is a good idea to do so if you are in that situation.

At this point, it's difficult to justify not using an ORM on most projects that involve an object oriented programming language and a relational database.  Not having time for the learning curve ORMs require is the biggest reason not to use an ORM.  In the .NET world, there are solid, mature ORM options available.